# Device doesn't recognize 9 patch

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, nine-patch

I made some 9 patch images to use as a button, but the device doesn't recognize them.

9 patch image:

[image]

How eclipse shows it:

[image]

How my device shows it:

[image]

As you can see, the english button has two black pixels at the top and slovenian only has one. I did this to try if two pixels would work, but it still didn't.

I'm pretty sure I did everything right. Names are in the right format (name.9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your right border is not continuous. The right border defines the padding, and must be a continuous line (or a single pixel). You seem to simply have the logic inverted, but it should be like this instead:

[image: 9-patch]

Answer (score 0):

9-patch images have to be pre-compiled, when the one pixel border is removed and encoded to a PNG chunk. Your image is not being pre-compiled. That's why the black pixels still appear, and the image is not being correctly stretched.

Make sure your images are in one of the `drawable` folders, and their name ends with `.9.png`. If everything is right, try to clean and build your project.